# Search all keywords with tlmgr

Tags: latex, keyword, tex-live

I want to know how to find all TeX Live keywords. I'm using Windows 10 and TeX Live 2019. I have tried this command `tlmgr search ­­--list --keyword` but I did not receive the except result.

Comment: Share code with details and error if any

Comment: you might have a better chance at tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can find an overview of keywords at https://ctan.org/topics/cloud

Comment: It would be nice if you would include a link to @cfr's answer from which you got the syntax. This would give users trying to help you more context about the problem.

Comment: The link of @cfr's answers is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202767/using-fonts-installed-in-local-texlive/500165#500165

Comment: I have tried the syntax of cfr'answers but no results. i precise that i use windows 10 and texlive 2019

Comment: X-post https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/7142/liste-des-keywords-de-texlive

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is no longer possible.

Looking at https://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr-news.html it says

> tlmgr revision 35841 (released 24dec14): remove taxonomy searching, since upstream data is no longer maintained.

An archived version of the taxonomy list is available from https://web.archive.org/web/20121120023458/http://az.ctan.org/keyword