# List of all keywords of texlive manager

Tags: latex, tex-live

I want to know the syntax which show me list of the all keywords of texlive manager. i'm using windows 10 and texlive 2019

Comment: What is the difference to your previous question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search all keyword with tlmgr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053002/search-all-keyword-with-tlmgr)